# SoundBoard Change Audio output to Virtual Audio Cable

Tags: java, javafx, audio, output

I wish to make my own SoundBoard and it works just fine. I want to change the audio output of my program to a different device but I don't know how.

If I overlooked an already existing thread I'm sorry but I have tried to find something that will work for me for days now.

I tried this and it shows all connected audio Devices.
But I don't know how to select one and then play a sound on it.

```
Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

        for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(mixerInfo[i].getName());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mixerInfo to get your mixer.

```
Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[idx]);
```

I'm assuming you are outputting via a SourceDataLine. The SDL can be obtained as follows:

```
SourceDataLine sdl = mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
```

Assumes dataLineInfo was obtained previously, from something like the following:

```
        Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, 
                audioFormat);
```

Comment: Im using the javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer; to output my mp3 sounds.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how javafx audio identifies lines. I've only dealt with the javax.sound.sampled library. I'd recommend making use of it, but it doesn't have built in support for mp3 decoding as the javafx audio does. One has to use an external library for that (e.g., from javazoom). Sorry not to be more help!

Comment: ok. Thank you anyway.
Unfortunately i did not find a way to do it too.